# C# Word Interop get page column from range

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-automation

I use a three-column word document. After I have inserted text and paragraphs dynamically, i would like to find out in which column it is located. Is there a way to find out the column of the document using the range? if necessary, it would help to know the page distance from the left.

```
// Paragraph   
var range = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(@"\EndOfDoc").Range;
Word.Paragraph par = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(range);
par.Range.InsertParagraphBefore();
par.Range.Text = "Paragraph";
par.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
par.Range.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);

// Get Page Column
```

Comment: Try to parse tables. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f748dd86-047b-4dee-aac2-fcf8f6214211/interop-how-to-get-the-count-of-tables-in-a-word-document?forum=worddev

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484422/word-interop-using-tables

Comment: I do not have Word on this machine but see wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage from [WdInformation Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdinformation?view=word-pia). Something like `left = (float)par.Range.get_Information(
            Word.WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage);`

Comment: @feihoa This question is about *newspaper* columns, not tables...

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing in the object model to return the `TextColumn` index of a range or selection. The reasoning is probably similar to that of why there's no `Line` or `Page` object in the Word object model - the content is always "in flux" due to how Word lays things out. So I think Justin's suggestion is probably as close as you're going to get...